# How to select all textareas and textboxes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select all textboxes and textareas, e.g:

```
<input type='text' />
```

and

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

on a page and have the property `style.width="90%";` applied to them?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').css({width: '90%'});
```

That uses standard CSS selectors, jQuery also has a set of pseudo-selector filters for various form elements, for example:

```
$(':text').css({width: '90%'});
```

will match all `<input type="text">` elements. See [Selectors documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) for more info.

Comment: :text selector wont select textareas (atleast in latest jQuery). I also wanted to add something from the jQuery documentation about the :text selector: "Because :text is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :text cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="text"] instead."

Comment: jquery plans drop sizzle in v4.0 ( https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/ ). With that in mind the special jquery selectors should be used carefully to prevent compatibility issues.

Answer (score 14):

Password boxes are also textboxes, so if you need them too:

```
$("input[type='text'], textarea, input[type='password']").css({width: "90%"});
```

and while file-input is a bit different, you may want to include them too (eg. for visual consistency):

```
$("input[type='text'], textarea, input[type='password'], input[type='file']").css({width: "90%"});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("**:**input[type=text], :input[type='textarea']").css({width: '90%'});
```

Comment: Why post the same answer twice? If there is something special about the minor differences, please explain them!

Comment: I personally appreciate knowing about jQuery's :input pseudo-selector. +1 for showing me something new.

Comment: :input[type='textarea'] doesn't work with latest jQuery. Must use textarea.

Answer (score 1):

```
names = [];
$('input[name=text], textarea').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        names.push( input.attr('name') );
        //input.attr('id');
    }
);
```

it select all textboxes and textarea in your DOM, where $.each function iterates to provide name of ecah element.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$(":input")`

Example disabling all inputs (textarea, input text, etc):

```js
$(":input").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea>Tetarea</textarea>
  <input type="text" value="Text">
  <label><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</label>
</form>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```