# jquery select all textboxes in a listview

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a listview which is databound to X items. On a submit button click I would like to use jquery to go through the listview rows and do basic form validation. This validation isn't systems critical so I am not worried about someone manipulating or sending back malicious scripts. It is things like, you must have a firstname,lastname. So on and so forth.

**Any ideas on how to do this in jquery without using the clientID (lvBob$ct10$txtName) would be great. Thank you very much**

Sorry question seems to be a little ambigious

To eleberate I would like to iterate over X amount of rows with X amount of columns
that are rendered in a listview. Validate each column based on my buisness logic and spawn an error message for each failure to validate.

Psuedocode

```
for each row in Listview
{
row.txt1 != null
{return "error message"}
}
```

But I would like to do this in jquery.

Comment: updated question to be less ambiguous

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. This jquery is what I used

```
 $(this).find('input.firstName');
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get around selecting textboxes without referencing the ClientID of the ListView.  First wrap the ListView in a div and then select based on all of the textboxes contained within that div.

The following code will iterate through each textbox using jQuery:

```
$('#myDiv input[type=text]').each(
   function( intIndex ){
      // Do processing here on each textbox using $(this)
   }
);
```

You'll need to update the above code for your specific business requirements but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Have you googled it? First hit I got on google was this: [How to select all textareas and textboxes using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825710/how-to-select-all-textareas-and-textboxes-using-jquery)

According to that link you can try the something like: `$('li input[type=text]')`. If you need what type of data that is in the textbox you can add classes to the textboxes.