# Disable/Enable textField in Grails?

Tags: jquery, grails

I have an edit form which allows users to edit and update on a domain object. I have various text boxes that are of this form:

```
<g:textField name="name" value="${managementInstance?.name}" />
<g:textField name="websiteUrl" value="${managementInstance?.websiteUrl}" />
```

Based on the site http://jetlogs.org/2007/12/16/jquery-disabled-and-readonly-inputs/
I can create a read only and click enabled textbox or textField using jquery, but giving an id and function to every textField is inefficient.

Is there any way I can access each  element and provide the disable and enable action?

Answer (score 0):

E.g. like this (jQuery based solution):

```
<div>
    <g:textField name="name" value="${managementInstance?.name}" />
    <span class="toggleDisable">Disable</span>
</div>
<div>
    <g:textField name="websiteUrl" value="${managementInstance?.websiteUrl}" />
    <span class="toggleDisable">Disable</span>
</div>

<script>
     $(".toggleDisable").click(function() {
          $(this).parent().find("input").toggleClass("disable");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey crudolf. Thanks for the response. This method provides more work because each textField element will now need to have a class associated with it.

Comment: what? i dont get your point. what class is associated with each textfield? its the same for all..

Comment: I am sorry. I stated that wrong each textField will now have a <span> element with the associated class. What if the number of text inputs are unknown? There needed to be a general way.

Comment: looking at the web page you have posted, there is an activate/deactivate link. for sake of simplicity i replaced it with an span. you justneed the 3 lines of JS code and to wrap your input field into any kind of html element, which you need to since you want to layout your field ;) so i dont see a more general way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input:text').each(function(){
            console.log("Hi");
            $(this).attr("readonly",true);
    });

    $('input:text').click(function(){

            if ($(this).attr("readonly") == true)
            {
                $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
            }
    });     
});
</script>
```

This method provides each textField to initially be set to readonly and each textField has a click associated with it as well.

After searching some more I found: [How to select all textareas and textboxes using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825710/how-to-select-all-textareas-and-textboxes-using-jquery)

Thanks