# Detecting Textarea Object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a bit of jQuery to suppress a carriage return when customers are filling out our forms:

```
$('form.eForm:not(.suppress-submit-on-enter-key-disabled) :not(:button, :submit)').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    // Cancel submit event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Give focus to next input element
    $(':input').eq($(this).index(':input') + 1).focus();
  }
});
```

However, it has also managed to suppress the carriage returns on our Comment boxes.

It seemed simple enough to add a `textarea` checker like the existing code has to check for **:not (:button, :submit)**:

```
$('form.eForm:not(.suppress-submit-on-enter-key-disabled) :not(:button, :submit, :textarea)').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    // Cancel submit event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Give focus to next input element
    $(':input').eq($(this).index(':input') + 1).focus();
  }
});
```

Whoops! **:not (:button, :submit, :textarea)** didn't work, because it seems that `textarea` is not defined for this part of jQuery.

How do others detect these **TextArea** controls?

**Update:**

One of the people who posted an answer on here turned out to have the solution.

The `eForm` class that all of our forms are generated from was somehow catching this.

It took my manager and I a couple of hours hammering on this to get it resolved, but in the end all I needed to do was to only handle events from an **Input** control.

Here is our end result:

```
$('form.eForm:not(.suppress-submit-on-enter-key-disabled) :input:not(:button, :submit, textarea)').keypress(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 13){
    // Cancel submit event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Give focus to next input element
    $(':input').eq($(this).index(':input') + 1).focus();
  }
});
```

Special thanks to [Khawer Zeshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875048/khawer-zeshan) for providing that Fiddle. It proved to me that there was something deeper wrong with my code.

Comment: A quick search leads me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/825720/778118)...

Comment: Getting index of an element in the set? `$('input').index(this)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you use `id` for single `textarea` and `class` name for multiple selectors?

For only one `textarea`:

```
$('#textareaid').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    // Cancel submit event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Give focus to next input element
    $(':input').eq($(this).index(':input') + 1).focus();
  }
});
```

For multiple fields use the `class name` and apply the same class for those fields:

```
$('.textareaClass').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    // Cancel submit event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Give focus to next input element
    $(':input').eq($(this).index(':input') + 1).focus();
  }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nZ5Kj/)**

Comment: That would be nice, but this is going into our company's `core.js` file, that all pages use. And, I really do not want to suppress `13` for the `textarea` controls.

Comment: just apply the class for which you want to suppress `13`. See the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nZ5Kj/)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same concern in mind, and created this very simple jQuery plugin for it

https://github.com/aymanrb/jquery-tabable-required