# Text area not valided bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my tabbed form all text field validate but text area does not validate.

My code:

```
  allNextBtn.click(function(){

      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url'],input[type='textarea']"),
          isValid = true;
      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
              isValid = false;
              $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
      }


      if (isValid)
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });
```

Here `input[type='textarea']` does not work.

Comment: Try using this ('input[type=text], textarea') for the textarea selector. You can [read more in this SO post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825710/how-to-select-all-textareas-and-textboxes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url'],input[type='textarea']")
```

instead of that write

```
curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url'],textarea")
```

and for select and radio

add this

```
curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url'],textarea,select,input[type='radio']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use input[type='textarea'], instead use only textarea inside curStep.find