# Addressing only text input fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, label

Hi I am trying to address only text fields so that I can hide the labels only for those.
I still want labels for checkboxes and readio buttons to be visible.
The code for hiding works but it hides all labels.

The script must work for all cases, no matter what the fields might be or how they are named.
So how would I get this to address only labels for text input fields:

```
$("label").each(function () {
```

I can't seem to work it out.

This is sample of the html:

```
<p class="form-field pd-text">
 <label class="field-label" for="229122">E-post</label>
 <input type="text" name="229122" id="229122" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" />
</p>
<p class="form-field pd-checkbox">
 <label class="field-label" for="229122">Example checkbox</label>
 <span class="value"><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="229122" id="229122" value="25034" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="229122">false</label>
 </span></span>
</p>
```

Comment: `$("input[type='text']")` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825710/how-to-select-all-textareas-and-textboxes-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map` to find the matching label based on its `for=` attribute:

```
var labels = $("input[type='text']").map(function() {
    return $("label[for=" + this.id + "]").toArray()
})
labels.hide();
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdtt8toe/

**Note** this requires that the `id=` is unique, which it must be (and is in the fiddle) but is *not* in your code.  So with your html, all the labels will be found as the checkbox has the same id as the textbox.

Alternatively, you can make assumptions about the DOM hierarchy.  Eg:

```
$("input[type='text']").parent().find("label")
```

to find all the labels in the same container.  This will find both ones in front and behind and can have other elements inbetween (unlike `.prev`!)

In your case, you might prefer to go to nearest `.form-field`:

```
$("input[type='text']").closest(`.form-field`).find("label")
```

Comment: the question not says write all the ways that can be solved this problem
@tove simpaly says he is trying to address only text fields so that I can hide the labels only for those. don't put extra afford he might be confused.

Comment: The first would work with normal html, but not OPs. the second won't find the second label, the third will only work in this scenario and so not useful as an SO answer.  It's normal to provide *working* alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

**try this** `$('[type=text]').prev().hide();`

if in any case your move your label before input to two level back or forward.
you can target like like that

```
 var labelFor = $('[type=text]').attr('id');
 $("label[for="+labelFor+"]").hide()
```

Comment: Assumes the label is *directly* infront of the input.

Comment: not assumes just have a look structure posted on question

Comment: The question doesn't say "how can I find *this* label", it says how "can I find the matching label".  Your solution will only work in *this* exact, one-off, *sample* scenario, thus incorrectly assuming the html for *all* scenarios.

Comment: Now your edit will only find the *first* label: https://jsfiddle.net/rdtt8toe/1/  (and breaks on OPs code where the ID is incorrectly reused).

Comment: id is unique so it never be use multiple time and in other case label is use for focus on that input when you have multiple label with same it wrong structure and useless work of label

Comment: @freedomn-m please accept this is correct way as well don't try to make afraid to others

Comment: Yes - it's correct that the ID should be unique.   Yes - this bit is correct `$('[type=text]')`.   No - using `.attr` is not correct as it only affects one label as demonstrated in the fiddle.  As per the question: *"I am trying to address only text fields"* - plural.

Comment: To clarify: I'm not saying this answer does not answer OPs question as presented (otherwise I'd downvote it, which I haven't).  I'm trying to improve the answer so that it can be of use to future users with a similar scenario (similar, but not exactly the same).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$("input[type='text']").prev('label').hide();
```

```html
<p class="form-field pd-text">
 <label class="field-label" for="229122">E-post</label>
 <input type="text" name="229122" id="229122" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" />
</p>
<p class="form-field pd-checkbox">
 <label class="field-label" for="229122">Example checkbox</label>
 <span class="value"><span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="229122" id="229122" value="25034" onchange="" />
  <label class="inline" for="229122">false</label>
 </span></span>
</p><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Assumes the label is *directly* infront of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a custom class to the label for text input

```
<p class="form-field pd-text">
    <label class="field-label text-label" for="229122">E-post</label>
    <input type="text" name="229122" id="229122" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" />
</p>
<p class="form-field pd-checkbox">
    <label class="field-label" for="229122">Example checkbox</label>
    <span class="value"><span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="229122" id="229122" value="25034" onchange="" />
        <label class="inline" for="229122">false</label>
    </span></span>
</p>
```

then hide only those labels

```
$(".text-label").hide()
```

if you want to hide all **form-field** assign the custom class to that field

ie:

```
<p class="form-field pd-text text-label">
    <label class="field-label" for="229122">E-post</label>
    <input type="text" name="229122" id="229122" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" />
</p>
```